# What kind of faucet is this and how can I remove it?

Tags: bathroom, faucet

I've got an old bathroom faucet without identifiable markings. Additionally, I can't figure out how to remove the handles - the cold water handle is rusted and likely needs a new cartridge. I suspect there is some way to turn or pull the handles the handles, but they won't come off and I can't loosen them from beneath with a basin wrench. I'd like to save them if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: mysterious ancient rusted faucet]
[image: Picture from bottom]

Comment: That little knob on top might ply off showing a screw under it.

Comment: What does it all look like from the bottom?

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. We're not a discussion forum, so all information must be in your question.

Answer (score 3):

I have this same faucet but can't recall if it's a Pfister or Moen, but I think  Pfister.  Got it a Lowes.  It took me some time a few year ago to figure it out, but crip659 is correct... The little knob on top comes off to reveal a screw for removing the cap.  Use a pocket knife or other thin blade to get the knob off. *Don't let it go down the drain!*

Lowes or HD sells the cartridges but be sure to get the correct one... they're different for hot or cold.  Very easy to replace with a small adjustable wrench.  Generics are much cheaper than OEM.